# What do < or > mean in LDA/STA command?

Tags: 6502

I understand the basics of the 6502 instruction set but have come across this code which is confusing me.

Can't find any reference to these in the 6502 manuals I have.

What do the <  and > signify?

```
CLBASE  = $100
BPTR    = $25
ARM .BYT $1,$2  

LDA #<ARM
STA BPTR
LDA #>ARM
STA BPTR+1
LDA #>CLBASE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefix #< specifies the low byte of the operand, and #> specifies the high byte of the operand.

E.g.

```
LDA #>CLBASE ;This will be #$01
LDA #<CLBASE ;This will be #$00
```

There's an assembler convention across the range of 6502-derived devices supported by most assemblers, such as [ACME](https://sourceforge.net/p/acme-crossass/code-0/6/tree/trunk/docs/QuickRef.txt) for instance. Here's the relevant section from WDC's W65C816S 8/16–bit Microprocessor [datasheet](http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/wdc_w65c816s_oct_11_2018.pdf).

```
| Operand     | One Byte Result | Two Byte Result |
|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| #$01020304  | 04              | 0403            |
| #<$01020304 | 04              | 0403            |
| #>$01020304 | 03              | 0302            |
| #^$01020304 | 02              | 0201            |
```